# Use the result from a query table into another query

Tags: mysql

There are 3 different tables and from first table i get the "contact_id" and based on this i would like to do the SUM into the next 2 tables and then MINUS the tables as in the code bellow.
I am trying to use the result "contact_id" from the first query into the following queries

```
SELECT (
    SELECT `id`
    FROM `civicrm_contact`
    WHERE `first_name` LIKE 'test2'
) AS contact_id
```

=============================================================

```
SELECT (
    SELECT SUM(`total_amount`)
    FROM `civicrm_contribution`
    WHERE `contact_id`=
)
-
(
    SELECT SUM(`fee_amount`)
    FROM `civicrm_participant`
    WHERE `contact_id`= 
) As RemainingPoints
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your problem :

```
SELECT (
    SELECT SUM(`total_amount`)
    FROM `civicrm_contribution`
    WHERE `contact_id` in (SELECT `id` FROM `civicrm_contact` WHERE `first_name` LIKE 'test2' ) AS contact_id) 
)
-
(
    SELECT SUM(`fee_amount`)
    FROM `civicrm_participant`
    WHERE `contact_id` in (SELECT `id` FROM `civicrm_contact` WHERE `first_name` LIKE 'test2' ) AS contact_id)
) As RemainingPoints
```

Comment: Thanks for your elaborated answer! I finally changed the structure and I used sub select in my query. thanks for the distinct hint which I did not know.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use subquery :

```
SELECT (
    SELECT SUM(`total_amount`)
    FROM `civicrm_contribution`
    WHERE `contact_id`= (SELECT `id` FROM `civicrm_contact` WHERE `first_name` LIKE 'test2' ) AS contact_id) 
)
-
(
    SELECT SUM(`fee_amount`)
    FROM `civicrm_participant`
    WHERE `contact_id`= (SELECT `id` FROM `civicrm_contact` WHERE `first_name` LIKE 'test2' ) AS contact_id)
) As RemainingPoints
```

Comment: The query may fail as the inner sub query can return more than one value. Use `in` instead of `=`

Comment: In this Case let's to use LIMIT 1.

Answer (score 0):

You should limit the result of the subquery to 1 otherwise it will result in an error, the best way is to match the name using `'='` instead of `'like'`

```
SELECT (
    SELECT SUM(`total_amount`)
    FROM `civicrm_contribution`
    WHERE `contact_id`= (SELECT `id` FROM `civicrm_contact` WHERE `first_name` LIKE 'test2' limit 1 ) AS contact_id) 
)
-
(
    SELECT SUM(`fee_amount`)
    FROM `civicrm_participant`
    WHERE `contact_id`= (SELECT `id` FROM `civicrm_contact` WHERE `first_name` LIKE 'test2' limit 1 ) AS contact_id)
) As RemainingPoints
```

Answer (score 0):

This could help you

```
SELECT @s:=1+1 ,@s + 4,@s-1
```

o/p -@s:=1+1|@s + 4 | @s-1

```
       2  |    6|   1
```